# Why is technically possible for init to be a shell script?

Tags: shell, init

I'm currently studying the boot process and composition of the different aspects of a GNU/Linux system and I can't rationaly explain this thing : you can write `init` inside an `initramfs` file as a shell script .

Init is supposed to be the first user-space process and the parent of all processes that are not spawned directly by the kernel . The PID of init is generally `1` which means it comes before everything else in the user space, and in that "everything" there should be your shell too .

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Now how things work when inside the `init` file I'm invoking a shell which is supposed to be a child process of the same process it is creating  ?

Comment: Are you looking for the https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) details?

Comment: @hargut no, it's more about the design and operation of the linux kernel

Answer (score 2):

A [shell based rootfs switch](https://landley.net/writing/rootfs-programming.html) is typically via `exec switch_root`  because [exec does not fork](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#EXECREF). Preserves the assumption of PID 1 is init.

This being Linux, of course that's far from the only way to do things. Each init system, indeed each distro, has their own packaging of initramfs. For example, systemd in initramfs.

Comment: if I understand this correctly : it runs inside the kernel memory space ? My scripts will basically have 100% access to all the "sensitive" areas inside the kernel . I'm assuming that `kexec` is also what lets `systemd` or `sysvinit` start .

Comment: You can start anything at boot from the kernel, it does not have to be `init`. Typically the bootloader reads the kernel and initramfs from the disk, and then executes the first process, which then prepares the file system mounts and switches into the "real" system by switching root.

Comment: What is started by the kernel can be defined using the kernel parameters (config) or boot flags such as `init=/your/program/to/exec/as/pid/1`. This can be directly a shell or `systemd` or a sysv init script. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

Comment: Further it is as well possible to completely avoid initramfs as this is not required. Such configurations are not common with popular linux distribution, but technically it is not a must.

Comment: https://www.pks.mpg.de/~mueller/docs/suse10.1/suselinux-manual_en/manual/cha.boot.html